# Start node server, load the page at specific time of the day daily

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, bash

I want to be able to start a node server, load a page in localhost at 8am daily, run the server for few minutes(as I'm sending an email based on the content loaded on the page) and then do the same one a daily recurring basis. Any pointers on efficiently doing this with minimal tools?
The tools available at my disposal are bash script, nodejs and the ones available in a window machine where I have the setup.

Comment: That's probably best done using a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with this nodejs packages but that will make it hard to re-run the server once its terminated.

So the option is the cron job and some modification at you nodejs code.

You need to create two cron job,

- one will start nodejs server
- the second will hit the endpoint

`crontab -e`

Then create

```
#this will start every day at 08:00 am
0 8 * * * node /path_to_app/app.js > /path_to_app/logs/log-file-$(date).txt
# this will start everyday at 08:01 am
1 8 * * * curl http://localhost:3000/startjob
```

Your nodejs code

```
app.use('/startjob', function(req,res){
    console.log("starting job");
    // do steps here
    res.send("job done")
    console.log("going to exit node process");
    var date = new Date();
    var current_hour = date.getHours();
    console.log(date)
    process.exit(0)
});
```

- `> path_to_app/logs/log-file-$(date).txt` this will also write logs of your nodejs script to file

[image]

**updated:**

```
  1 8 * * * google-chrome http://localhost:3000/startjob
```

Comment: Ok thanks. It is also important for me to use chrome with an extension to load the page with the content. Will I be able to achieve with this setup? Sorry did not mention this piece of info in the original question.

Comment: yes, of course, all you need to change the second cron job `1 8 * * * google-chrome http://localhost:3000/startjob` this will open a browser and you need to activiate extension on page open

Comment: Due to some reason, crontab on my Mac is not working. I'll shall try on a different machine and post the outcome

Comment: Fixed the crontab issue and the recommendation works on MacOS.

Comment: awsome. glad to know @neelmeg